# vmware subscriber multiplemachines problem

Tags: ros, subscribe, multiplemachines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I try to connect my Ubuntu system [a] to a virtual Ubuntu machine (VMware)[b] by network.
It seems to work. I can ping and ssh from one to the other machine.
Furthermore when I start a roscore on [a] I can run for example "rosrun rospy_tutorial listener.py" on machine [b] and it finds the roscore. If I start the talker on [a] I can see on [b] the topic "/chatter" and the node "/talker_3586_1356978819462".

But if I run the listener now on [b] (still with the roscore of [a]) it doesn't hear anything. I have no clue, where the problem is. Maybe someone can help me with that?

Some things that I have already tried:

- Start a talker and listener only on machine [a] works.
- Start a talker and listener only on machine [b] (with core of [a]) works.
- Previously I had the Ubuntu system [a] also on a virtual machine and this example worked with both virtual machines [a] and [b] running in windows.

Best Jonathan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51264/vmware-subscriber-multiplemachines-problem/) by [hej](https://answers.ros.org/users/3876/hej/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS relies on bidirectional communications.  Make sure you work all the way through the [Network Setup Guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) This sounds like you have hostnames which cannot lookup fully on both machines.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1